# Poderosa SSH returns "user authentication failed" when using the right password

Tags: ssh, putty, authentication

The company I work for has instituted 2-factor authentication (PIN plus RSA token) to some servers.

The account I am using is not enabled for that (so I just type in a password), but I can't connect. I got instructions on how to enable this in Exceed with PuTTY, but I prefer Poderosa. The only error I get is a popup

> user authentication failed

This is NOT a password issue. Our passwords have not changed. I can get to some servers and then ssh over, but I'd rather go direct.

I have screenshots of the instructions for exceed/PuTTY, so I can't copy and paste. Basically

- settings →
- security tab →
- properties button →
- click a button that looks like a pencil →
- list of checkboxes
- de-select checkbox entered password
- check the box for: keyboard interaction click ok.
- clear out the password field so you get a popup

Comment: Are you sure it's not a server configuration issue where that server just no longer accepts password authentication?

Comment: Hi Bob, you might get more participation in this question if you accept answers to previous questions.  It is likely the 0% accept is putting people off.